# In what infinite-dimensional vector spaces do Pythagoras's identity apply?

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, inner-products

This question stemmed from when I was trying to understand Parseval's identity and understanding how we could exchange the sum and integral in the proof.

In general, I understand that two of the properties of an inner product space are

$$\left\langle a_1\vec{x_1}+a_2\vec{x_2},\,\vec{y}\right\rangle=a_1\left\langle\vec{x_1}, \vec{y}\right\rangle+a_2\left\langle\vec{x_2},\vec{y}\right\rangle$$

and

$$\left\langle\vec{x},\,b_1\vec{y_1}+b_2\vec{y_2}\right\rangle=\overline{b_1}\left\langle\vec{x}, \vec{y_1}\right\rangle+\overline{b_2}\left\langle\vec{x},\vec{y_2}\right\rangle$$

So for an $n$-dimensional vector space, we have orthonormal unit vectors $\hat e_1, \hat e_2, \cdots, \hat e_n$ spanning the space, allowing to represent any vector as

$$\vec{v}=\sum^n_{i=1}a_i\hat e_i$$

Which resultingly tells us that

$$\left\|\vec v\right\|^2=\left\langle\vec{v},\vec{v}\right\rangle=\left\langle\sum^n_{i=1}a_i\hat e_i,a_j\hat e_i\right\rangle=\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}a_i\left\langle\hat e_i,\sum^n_{j=1}a_j\hat e_j\right\rangle=\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}a_i\overline{a_j}\left\langle\hat e_i,\hat e_j\right\rangle=\sum^n_{i=1}\left|a_i\right|^2$$

Which is Pythagoras's identity.

This works because we can apply the above properties a finite amount of times.

However, what I fail to understand is why this is also true for vector spaces of infinite dimensions. While [orthonormal bases exist if AC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis?useskin=vector#Existence), it isn't necessarily the case that a property of a function holds when it is applied infinitely many times (c.f. [Riemann's series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem?useskin=vector)). This problem seems even worse when you look at uncountably infinite dimensional spaces. And yet (at least with functions on a real interval/on the complex plane) this identity holds via Parseval's identity/theorem.

Therefore, my question is: under what conditions can we write

$$\vec{v}=\sum_i a_i\hat e_i\Rightarrow \left\|\vec{v}\right\|^2=\sum_i|a_i|^2$$

Comment: I think it's a lot more common to say $\| v\|^2=\langle v,v\rangle$.

Comment: I think you should read the section on Hilbert spaces in Folland's real analysis text (theorem 5.26 about Bessel's inequality, and theorem 5.27 on the characterization of orthonormal bases). Bessel's inequality particularly restricts it to the case of having only at most countably many non-zero coefficients.

Comment: @Arthur oops yeah, meant $\|\vec{v}\|^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true in any Hilbert space (that is, any complete inner product space), as long as your axioms (typically, choice, but something weaker for the separable case) give you an orthonormal basis (that is, a maximal orthonormal set).

Given a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{e_j\}$, one can work as this:

- show that if $\sum_j|a_j|^2<\infty$, then the series $\sum_ja_je_j$ converges.
- consider the set $$K=\{\sum_ja_je_j:\ \sum_j|a_j|^2<\infty\}.$$ It is easy to show that $K^\perp=\{0\}$. For any element in $K$ the continuity of the inner product allows one to do
  $$
  \langle\sum_ja_je_j,\sum_ja_je_j\rangle=\sum_{k,j}a_j\overline{a_k}\langle e_j,e_k\rangle=\sum_j|a_j|^2.
  $$
- show that $K$ is closed. This usually requires to see that $K$ is isometrically isomorphic to $\ell^2(J)$, and because this latter Hilbert space is rather explicit, one can show that it is complete.
- Now $$H=\{0\}^\perp=K^{\perp\perp}=\overline K=K.$$

---

**Edit: clarifications based on the comments.**

- $H=\{0\}^\perp$, simply because all elements are orthogonal to $0$.
- One can define series over any index set, countable or not. The series is still defined as the limit of the partial sums, but now the partial sums are considered over the net of all finite sets, ordered by inclusion. This is often called *unconditional convergence*. In the case of numerical series it is equivalent to absolute convergence. But it is the right notion to consider when doing series over arbitrary index sets.
- $\ell^2(J)=\{a:J\to\mathbb C|\ \sum_J|a_j|^2<\infty\}$. One considers this as an inner product space with $\langle a,b\rangle=\sum_Ja_j\overline{b_j}$. There is a standard proof that it is complete, often appearing in measure theory texts, as this space is $L^2(J)$ with the counting measure.

Comment: Hi, so unfortunately I don't know that much about functional analysis and I've only been looking at this out of interest. I've been able to prove the convergence of $\sum_j a_j\hat{e}_j$ and the continuity of the inner product but do you mind explaining

 - What is $\ell^2(J)$?

 - Why is $H=\{0\}^\perp$?

 - What if the Hilbert space has uncountably infinitely many dimensions (leading to uncountably infinite size of the orthonormal basis)? We can justify the convergence of $\sum_j a_j\hat{e}_j$ because it forms a Cauchy sequence for a countable basis, but not for uncountable.

Comment: Sorry for the earlier comment lacking spaces, couldn't figure out how to include them. Anyways, clarifying for the convergence of the series part - I was able to justify that $\sum^k_{j=0}a_j\hat{e}_j$ converges for a countable basis by setting $\vec{x}_k=\sum^k_{j=0}a_j\hat{e}_j$, which is a Cauchy sequence. However, if the basis is uncountable, then the above sequence would have to be uncountably infinitely long, which doesn't seem to make sense for me.

Comment: I have edited some clarifications in. I hope they help.

Comment: Thanks, that explained a lot. One last thing, why is $K^{\perp\perp}=\overline{K}$ and not just $K$?

Comment: Orthogonals are always closed; an orthogonal can never be equal to a non-closed subspace.  In any case, it is fairly easy to prove the equality $K^{\perp\perp}=\overline{K}$.

Comment: I'm still unsure about this part. If we have $a\perp b$, then $\langle a, b\rangle=0$, so $\langle b, a\rangle=\overline{0}=0$ and hence $b\perp a$, so perpendicularity is symmetric, so I don't see the need for the conjugate. But anyways this does answer my question so I'll accept it.

Comment: The bar means closure.

Comment: OK, that makes sense.